# core text - draw simple text on a custom view in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have made a custom view, and in this custom view, I want to draw a simple text. I've been searching for couple hours and find no luck. The one that I've found on Apple documentation is hard to understand. Can anyone have a sample or link to tutorial ? Thanks.

Comment: Most people would just add a `UILabel` subview. If you really want get into the weeds of drawing text, see [CoreText](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH1-SW1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very simple example. You only need to call drawAtPoint:withAttributes: on your string inside drawRect: of your custom view.

```
@implementation CustomView {
    NSDictionary *attributes;
    NSString *theText;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]};
    theText = @"This is my text";
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [theText drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(5, 5) withAttributes:attributes];
}
```